# Calling lxml's .xpath() from inside a PyV8 context with invalid xpath crashes Python. Why?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, v8, embedded-v8

Calling lxml's .xpath() from inside a PyV8 context with invalid xpath crashes Python. Why?

Is there a way I can use lxml to check if s is a valid xpath expression before attempting to use it in a call to .xpath?

P.S.: Extra info in case it's relevant: I'm on Python 2.6, Win 7 32bit running on a Macbook (Intel's Core2 Duo P7450 CPU)

Script to reproduce error:

```
import PyV8
import urllib2
from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring
c = PyV8.JSContext()
c.enter()
doc_text = urllib2.urlopen("http://sfbay.craigslist.org/roo/").read()
doc = fromstring(doc_text)
c.locals['doc'] = doc
output = c.eval("doc.xpath('bad expression');")
```

**EDIT:** Changed title and added script to reproduce error. Originally the question was about why a leading ':' character in the xpath expression caused the error, but the problem can be caused by any invalid xpath expression when xpath is called from within a PyV8 context.

Comment: A small example may be helpful in duplicating the error. Also, what version of libxml2 and libxslt?

Comment: By "crashes Python", do you mean "raises an XPathEvalError"?

Comment: @DSM - I mean Windows displays an error saying "Python has stopped working" and there is no accompanying trace printout out to the console. This is the first time I've seen Python do that - every other time something breaks it will give me a helpful stack trace printout to console to say what went wrong.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams My apologies - please see update. By creating a script to reproduce this I've discovered it's not actually caused by the ':' character at all. See question update for more.

Comment: Excellent. Now you've added a powerful debugging tool to your arsenal.